# Spacer added to inner wxBoxSizer doesn't work in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have an issue with spacer inside of the inner wxBoxSizer.
Here is the sample code.

```
class Frame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    Frame()
        : wxFrame(nullptr,
                  wxID_ANY,
                  wxEmptyString,
                  wxDefaultPosition,
                  wxSize(600, 200))
    {
        wxPanel* panel = new wxPanel(this);

        // Some OUTER SIZER
        wxBoxSizer* mainS = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

        // INNER HORIZONTAL SIZER
        wxBoxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);

        wxStaticText* text = new wxStaticText(panel, wxID_ANY, wxT("Some Text"));        
        sizer->Add(text, 0, wxALL, 5);

        wxComboBox* comboBox = new wxComboBox(panel, wxID_ANY, wxT("Combo"));
        sizer->Add(comboBox, 0, wxALL, 5);

        // SPACER
        sizer->Add(0, 0, 1, wxEXPAND, 5);

        wxButton* button = new wxButton(panel, wxID_ANY, wxT("Some button"));
        sizer->Add(button, 0, wxALL, 5);
        mainS->Add(sizer, 0, wxALL, 5); 

        panel->SetSizer(mainS);

        // PANEL SIZER
        wxBoxSizer* panelSizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
        panelSizer->Add(panel, 1, wxEXPAND, 5);

        SetSizer(panelSizer);
        Layout();
        Centre(wxBOTH);
    }
};

class WxguiApp
    : public wxApp
{
public:
    bool OnInit() override
    {
        Frame* w = new Frame();
        w->Show();
        SetTopWindow(w);

        return true;
    }
};

IMPLEMENT_APP(WxguiApp);
```

If I remove outer sizer spacer starts working fine. Is it bug in my code? Or maybe some issue with wxWidgets?

I couldn't find answer, maybe someone help? wxWidgets 3.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your inner sizer (`sizer`) won't expand in the horizontal direction because you didn't tell its parent sizer (`mainS`) to do it when adding it, so your spacer will always be 0 pixels wide, which is its initial and minimal width.

To fix this, you just need to change the `mainS->Add(sizer, 0, wxALL, 5)` line to use `wxALL | wxEXPAND`.

Additionally, I *strongly* encourage you to look at using `wxSizerFlags` instead of the cryptic syntax shown above. And, last and really least, but still worth mentioning, prefer using much more readable `AddStretchSpacer()` to the confusing `Add(0, 0, 1, wxEXPAND, 5)` call (it's confusing because expanding your spacer doesn't do anything and border size is not taken into account without any border flags).

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped.